# Behaviour of Chern class under deformation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology, deformation-theory

The setting is the following: $f: X \rightarrow T$ is a smooth projective map of complex algebraic varieties, and $L$ is a line bundle on $X$.

My question is the following: is $c_1(L_t)$ (in cohomology) independent on $t \in T$? In the example I am looking at (semiample deformations of ample line bundles, Positivity in Algebraic Geometry, by Lazarsfeld) there is this senstence: "On the other hand, the homomorphism given by cup product with $c_1(L_t)^b$, being defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ and topologically determined, are independent of $t \in T$.".

The goal of the example I am working out is to conclude that the map "capping with $c_1(L_0)^b$" ($X_0$ is a special fibre) is injective (on a certain cohomology group) since it holds true for the fibres $X_t$, $t \neq 0$. So, maybe the question might not make complete sense beyond what is explicitly needed.

What I have guessed so far is that my map gives me a complex analytic family, and hence the fibres are diffeomorphic as real manifolds. So it makes sense to identify their cohomologies. The statement about the line bundle seem very intuitive, but nevertheless I have no clue how to see the claim above.

Both full answers and references are welcome!

Comment: I already don't understand how you're identifying the cohomologies of the fibers. I could believe that the cohomologies organize into a local system on $T$, but that just means that a choice of homotopy class of path between two points gives an identification between the cohomologies; in general this identification depends on the path. For the identification to be unique $T$ must in addition be simply connected.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe I am asking more than what can be argued from the context. What matters in the example is to conclude that the map on a special fibre $X_0$ is injective, and it is used that it is true for the fibres $X_t$ with $t \neq 0$. Would it make more sense to ask this instead?